# What are C classes for a NLLLoss loss function in Pytorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I'm asking about C classes for a [NLLLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=nllloss#torch.nn.NLLLoss) loss function.

The documentation states:

> The negative log likelihood loss. It is useful to train a classification problem with C classes.

Basically everything after that point depends upon you knowing what a C class is, and I thought I knew what a C class was but the documentation doesn't make much sense to me. Especially when it describes the expected inputs of `(N, C) where C = number of classes`. That's where I'm confused, because I thought a C class refers to the *output* only. My understanding was that the C class was a one hot vector of classifications. I've often found in tutorials that the `NLLLoss` was often paired with a `LogSoftmax` to solve classification problems.

I was expecting to use `NLLLoss` in the following example:

```py
# Some random training data
input = torch.randn(5, requires_grad=True)
print(input)  # tensor([-1.3533, -1.3074, -1.7906,  0.3113,  0.7982], requires_grad=True)
# Build my NN (here it's just a LogSoftmax)
m = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=0)
# Train my NN with the data
output = m(input)
print(output)  # tensor([-2.8079, -2.7619, -3.2451, -1.1432, -0.6564], grad_fn=<LogSoftmaxBackward>)
loss = nn.NLLLoss()
print(loss(output, torch.tensor([1, 0, 0])))
```

The above raises the following error on the last line:

> ValueError: Expected 2 or more dimensions (got 1)

We can ignore the error, because clearly I don't understand what I'm doing. Here I'll explain my intentions of the above source code.

```py
input = torch.randn(5, requires_grad=True)
```

Random 1D array to pair with one hot vector of `[1, 0, 0]` for training. I'm trying to do a binary bits to one hot vector of decimal numbers.

```py
m = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=0)
```

The documentation for `LogSoftmax` says that the output will be the same shape as the input, but I've only seen examples of `LogSoftmax(dim=1)` and therefore I've been stuck trying to make this work because I can't find a relative example.

```py
print(loss(output, torch.tensor([1, 0, 0])))
```

So now I have the output of the NN, and I want to know the loss from my classification `[1, 0, 0]`. It doesn't really matter in this example what any of the data is. I just want a loss for a one hot vector that represents classification.

At this point I get stuck trying to resolve errors from the loss function relating to expected output and input structures. I've tried using `view(...)` on the output and input to fix the shape, but that just gets me other errors.

So this goes back to my original question and I'll show the example from the documentation to explain my confusion:

```py
m = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)
loss = nn.NLLLoss()
input = torch.randn(3, 5, requires_grad=True)
train = torch.tensor([1, 0, 4])
print('input', input)  # input tensor([[...],[...],[...]], requires_grad=True)
output = m(input)
print('train', output, train)  # tensor([[...],[...],[...]],grad_fn=<LogSoftmaxBackward>) tensor([1, 0, 4])
x = loss(output, train)
```

Again, we have `dim=1` on `LogSoftmax` which confuses me now, because look at the `input` data. It's a `3x5` tensor and I'm lost.

Here's the documentation on the first input for the `NLLLoss` function:

> Input: (N, C)(N,C) where C = number of classes

The inputs are *grouped* by the number of classes?

So each *row* of the tensor input is associated with each *element* of the training tensor?

If I change the second dimension of the input tensor, then *nothing breaks* and I don't understand what is going on.

```py
input = torch.randn(3, 100, requires_grad=True)
# 3 x 100 still works?
```

So I don't understand what a C class is here, and I thought a C class was a classification (like a label) and meaningful only on the outputs of the NN.

I hope you understand my confusion, because shouldn't the shape of the inputs for the NN be independent from the shape of the one hot vector used for classification?

Both the code examples and documentations say that the shape of the inputs is defined by the number of classifications, and I don't really understand why.

I have tried to study the documentations and tutorials to understand what I'm missing, but after several days of not being able to get past this point I've decided to ask this question. It's been humbling because I thought this was going to be one of the easier things to learn.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically you are missing a concept of `batch`.

Long story short, every input to loss (and the one passed through the network) requires `batch` dimension (i.e. how many samples are used).

Breaking it up, step by step:

## Your example vs documentation

Each step will be each step compared to make it clearer (documentation on top, your example below)

### Inputs

```
input = torch.randn(3, 5, requires_grad=True)
input = torch.randn(5, requires_grad=True)
```

In the first case (docs), input with `5` features is created and `3` samples are used. In your case there is only `batch` dimension (`5` samples), you have no features **which are required**. If you meant to have one sample with `5` features you should do:

```
input = torch.randn(5, requires_grad=True)
```

### LogSoftmax

`LogSoftmax` is done across features dimension, you are doing it across batch.

m = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1) # apply over features
m = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=0) # apply over batch

It makes no sense usually for this operation as samples are independent of each other.

### Targets

As this is multiclass classification and each element in vector represents a sample, one can pass as many numbers as one wants (as long as it's smaller than number of features, in case of documentation example it's `5`, hence `[0-4]` is fine ).

```
train = torch.tensor([1, 0, 4])
train = torch.tensor([1, 0, 0])
```

I assume, you wanted to pass one-hot vector as target as well. PyTorch doesn't work that way as it's **memory inefficient** (why store everything as one-hot encoded when you can just pinpoint exactly the class, in your case it would be `0`).

Only outputs of neural network are one hot encoded in order to backpropagate error through all output nodes, it's not needed for targets.

## Final

**You shouldn't** use `torch.nn.LogSoftmax` **at all** for this task. Just use `torch.nn.Linear` as last layer and use `torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss` with your targets.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with you that the documentation for `nn.NLLLoss()` is far from ideal, but I think we can clarify your problem here, firstly, by clarifying that "class" is often used as a synonym of "category" in a Machine Learning context.

Therefore, when PyTorch is talking about `C` classes, it is actually referring to the *number of distinct categories* that you are trying to train your network on.
So, in the classical example of a categorical neural network trying to classify between "cats" and "dogs", `C = 2`, since it is either a cat or dog.

Specifically for this classification problem, it also holds that we only have *one single truth value* over the array of our categories (a picture cannot depict both a cat AND a dog, but always only either one), which is why we can conveniently indicate the corresponding category of an image by its index (let's say that `0` would indicate a cat, and `1` a dog). Now, we can simply compare the network output to the category we want.

BUT, in order for this to work, we need to also be clear what these loss values are referencing to (in our network output), since our network will generally make predictions *via a softmax over different output neurons*, meaning that we have generally more than a single value. Fortunately, PyTorch's `nn.NLLLoss` does this automatically for you.

Your above example with the `LogSoftmax` in fact only produces a single output value, which is a critical case for this example. This way, you basically only have an indication of whether or not something exists/doesn't exist, but it doesn't make much sense to use in a classification example, more so in a regression case (but that would require a totally different loss function to begin with).

Last, but not least, you should also consider the fact that we generally have 2D tensors as input, since batching (the simultaneous computation of multiple samples) is generally considered a necessary step to match performance. Even if you choose a batch size of 1, this still requires your inputs to be of dimension `(batch_size, input_dimensions)`, and consequently your output tensors of shape `(batch_size, number_of_categories)`.

This explains why most of the examples you find online are performing the `LogSoftmax()` over `dim=1`, since this is the "in-distribution axis", and not the batch axis (which would be `dim=0`).

If you simply want to fix your problem, the easiest way would be to extend your random tensor by an additional dimension (`torch.randn([1, 5], requires_grad=True)`), and then to compare by only one value in your output tensor (`print(loss(output, torch.tensor([1]))`)