# Tensor output from final layer is of the wrong shape in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, tensor, torch

I am building a sequence-to-label classifier, where the input data are text sequences and output labels are binary. The model is very simple, with GRU hidden layers and a Word Embeddings input layer. I want a `[n, 60]` input to output a `[n, 1]` label, but the Torch model returns a `[n, 60]` output.

My model, with minimal layers:

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, weights_matrix, hidden_size, num_layers):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.embedding, num_embeddings, embedding_dim = create_emb_layer(weights_matrix, True)
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.gru = nn.GRU(embedding_dim, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.out = nn.Linear(hidden_size, 1)
    def forward(self, inp, hidden):
        emb = self.embedding(inp);
        out, hidden = self.gru(emb, hidden)
        out = self.out(out);
        return out, hidden;

    def init_hidden(self, batch_size):
        return torch.zeros(self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_size).to(device);
```

Model Layers:

```
Model(
  (embedding): Embedding(184901, 100)
  (gru): GRU(100, 60, num_layers=3, batch_first=True)
  (out): Linear(in_features=60, out_features=1, bias=True)
)
```

Input shapes of my data are: `X` : `torch.Size([64, 60])`, and `Y` : `torch.Size([64, 1])`, for a single batch of size 64.

When I run the `X` tensor through the model, it should output a single label, however, the output from the classifier is `torch.Size([64, 60, 1])`. To run the model, I do the following:

```
for epoch in range(1):
    running_loss = 0.0;

    batch_size = 64;
    hidden = model.init_hidden(batch_size)
    for ite, data in enumerate(train_loader, 0):
        x, y = data[:,:-1], data[:,-1].reshape(-1,1)

        optimizer.zero_grad();

        outputs, hidden = model(x, hidden);

        hidden = Variable(hidden.data).to(device);
        loss = criterion(outputs, y);

        loss.backward();
        optimizer.step();

        running_loss = running_loss + loss.item();
        if ite % 2000 == 1999:
            print('[%d %5d] loss: %.3f'%(epoch+1, ite+1, running_loss / 2000))
        running_loss = 0.0;
```

When I print the `shape` of `outputs`, it is `64x60x1` rather than `64x1`. What I also don't get is how the `criterion` function is able to calculate the loss when the shapes of outputs and labels are inconsistent. With Tensorflow, this would always throw an error, but it doesn't with Torch.

Answer (score 1):

The output from your model is of shape `torch.Size([64, 60, 1])` i.e. 64 is the batch size, and (60, 1) corresponds `[n, 1]` as expected.

Assuming you're using [`nn.CrossEntropy(input, target)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss), it expected the input to be `(N,C)` and target to be `(N)`, where `C` is number of classes.

Your output is consistent, and hence loss is evaluated.

For example,

```
outputs = torch.randn(3, 2, 1)
target = torch.empty(3, 1, dtype=torch.long).random_(2)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction='mean')
print(outputs)
print(target)
loss = criterion(outputs, target)
print(loss)

# outputs
tensor([[[ 0.5187],
         [ 1.0320]],

        [[ 0.2169],
         [ 2.4480]],

        [[-0.4895],
         [-0.6096]]])
tensor([[0],
        [1],
        [0]])
tensor(0.5731)
```

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59718130/6210807).

Comment: This helps but doesn't answer my question. I think my problem is that predictions labels aren't the same dimension as the actual labels. I figure this is because I am not running the last layer output through any type of activation function or pooling.